# How to pop all view and go back to login view when user tap logout button

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I use a navigation controller for login view.From there i push to a tabbar controller using this code

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UITabBarController *obj=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tab"];
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=YES;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
```

How can navigate back to login view when user tap logout from profile screen (one of the tabbar controller view). I want a navigation bar in the login view. Can anyone please help.
I am using Storyboard.

Comment: I have posted my solution. Did you tried with that?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following :-

```
//This would pop to the given VC
[self.navigationController popToViewController:loginViewController animated:YES];

//This would pop to the root VC
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]
```

Update:-

```
- (IBAction)loginBtn{

  UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

  //U provided UITabBarController so replace at with your tabBar controller class like below ,TabViewController class is created.
  TabViewController *obj=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabBar"];

  self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=YES;   //navigation bar hidden so won't appear when back again to login if want to see then make it true in viewWillAppear/viewWillLoad.

  [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
 }
```

Also for coming back from tabBar to login VC follow below,

```
- (IBAction)popbtn:(id)sender{
 [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Also assgin the class to tabBar controller in storyboard along with storyboard id as below:-

[image]

Comment: @RajeshVijayakumar are you not getting error as ur using navigation controller and tabBar controller ?

Comment: if ur not having navigationBar onto ur tabBar controller then use this     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; this will lead to your login VC

Comment: @walle84..not getting any errors..but this navigation popToRootViewControllerAnimated method doesn't have any effect

Comment: could u provide a screen shot of ur storyboard? if possible

Comment: not able to post image due to reputaion issue in stackoverflow. Need min 10 reputation to post image. CAn u plz give ur mail id

Comment: @RajeshVijayakumar I have updated my post check out. Also if u don't see navigation bar when popBack to root VC it's bcoz u have hidden it when moving.

Comment: @walle84...i need to go back to my login view when user tap logout from profile screen. This was actually my question

Comment: U didn't read my post complete I guess as I have provided a method popbtn in the post for coming back from tabBar to rootVC(login VC) along with image and also explanation how to jump from login VC to TabBAr VC in my post. So please read it carefully.

Comment: @walle84...This is not working for me. I use the code below
- (IBAction)logoutUser:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
I call this from a tabbarcontroller view controller

   
}

Comment: Did u change this line "UITabBarController *obj=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tab"];" in ur code with what I have explained( that u need to assign ur tabBarController class and not UITabBarController)

Comment: See the image that I provided. In that image I have clicked on tabBArController in storyboard and given it custom class name along with storyboard id.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[[self.parentViewController navigationController] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Since you are pushing a `TabBarController`, you will need to pop using the TabBarController. `self.parentViewController` should give you the TabBarController.

Answer (score 0):

You can use just one line of code.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: question here is not to push a new view controller. Question is how to pop to login view controller which is already there in the navigation stack.

Comment: @NagaMalleshMaddali...but i am using separate navigation controller for login view and and tabbar views. When i call pop on tabbar it will not go to login view

Comment: when you use tabbar controller, then you can try like this.
    [self.tabBarController.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: @NagaMalleshMaddali...yes but this only pop the views that are in the tab bar controller

Comment: can you share your storyboard structure?

Comment: @mobile_dev... 
pho.to/7BLv2

Comment: ok, how did you push the tabView to the navigationView?
plz make a push segue between navigationController and tabViewController, and try again with the code. it will work.

Comment: and you should push the tabViewController with performSegueWithIdentifier method. it would be good to controller navigationViewController

Comment: UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil]; UITabBarController *obj=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tab"]; self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=YES; [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];

Answer (score 0):

```
id rootController = [[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] subviews] objectAtIndex:0] nextResponder];
if([rootController isKindOfClass:[LoginViewController class]]){
    //do something
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
else{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *rootViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"login"];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow setRootViewController:rootViewController];
}
```